# How to show extrusion or polygon wireframe in GLscene

Tags: delphi, glscene

I am learning how to use GLscene and am trying to render a stack of planar polygons that are layered so the polygons are coloured according to the layer number and each layer has a specific height (z depth).

GLextrusion seems to be ideal to render the polygons but I need to turn the fill on and off of specific layers so that only the wireframes are rendered.

The problem is, when the material is set to lines, the polygons are criss crossed with triangles. This seems to happen with other object types as well.

Is there any way to render the polygon outlines as a true wireframe ?

Comment: Actually what GLscene renders to you is true wireframe. You see graphics card always operate with triangles. So even if you want to render perfect square it will always be rendered as a set of two triangles. So in order to only get outlines of your own polygons I'm, afraid you will have to devise your own mechanism. Now I'm afraid I don't have enough experience in this field in order to provide you with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing has changed in the recent versions of GLScene there is no setting for that. The only solution I can remember is adding a *Lines* object to the scene and use the polygon outline. Then switch the visibility of the *extrusion* object and the *lines* object(s) as needed.

BTW, the outline of an *TGLExtrusionSolid* can be taken from its *Outline* property. Thus the *Lines* object can be built automatically using this information.